# Basic Dock/Anchor Styling

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I have a WPF project in C# I am working on.  I have a TabPage that contains three controls on it: 2 textboxes and a datagridview.  I want to have all three fit onto the page based on the size of the parent (the tabpage it is located on).

One textbox should be along the right side (ending at the other textbox), and the last text box along the full bottom.

GRID | TEXTBOX1

---  TEXTBOX ---

I have been experimenting with the Docking and Anchoring styles but I'm not sure how to use them properly with multiple elements on the page.

Currently I have the Textbox1 Dock.Right, Textbox2 Dock.Bottom.  I want the remaining DataGridView to fill whatever space is left.  However, using the Dock.Fill just fills the whole parent form and overlaps the textboxes.

Am I going about this properly?  I saw something on DockPanel's which had a "LastChildFill" property, but it didn't seem to apply to me (could be wrong?).  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`Grids`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx).

e.g. one `Grid` with two rows, top row containing another `Grid` with two columns.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition /> <!-- Fill All -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> <!-- Fit to content -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Why not just use one 2x2 grid?

Comment: That would be a viable option as well of course. (I usually avoid using `ColumnSpan` and the like though)

Comment: Guess it's just a matter of personal preference. I never use a sub-Grid unless not doing so would involve many small rows/columns in one section of a Grid

Comment: Could you provide a basic example of the implementation?  Sadly I am struggling even with the msdn's help =\.

Comment: @ImGreg: Added one, hopefully i understoof the layout correctly... (If you don't want the right TextBox to stretch down use `VerticalAlignment="Top"`, you also might want to set some `MinWidth`)

Comment: That should do it.  Thanks for the help @H.B.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be close. Use a `DockPanel` and set `DockPanel.Dock` on the controls as follows:

TextBox1: Right

TextBox2: Bottom

DataGridView: Fill